# User Activity page now responsive

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

And now it looks like this on mobile (Android Chrome):

[image: The activity menu is on three rows and the Answers and Reputation sections are overlapping.]

Apart from this broken implementation, I don't want this dashboard to be responsive. I use zooming and scrolling to focus on what I find important.

Was this tested with mobile resolutions, or should I just give up and use the mobile layout from now on?

Because the information density for the latter is appalling. I have good eyes and a high-res display.

Comment: Same issue with me

Comment: Definitely a design bug, but I don't think you're gonna have any luck with the "I prefer zooming to focus" method.

Comment: @Tyler yeah because some of the big guys do it, everyone's got to do it. My screen is capable of displaying more than six comments on one page. I hate "responsive" in the sense of "let's make everything bigger", and I can't imagine that I'm the only one.

Comment: If only this was working well...then it'd be lauded and celebrated as opposed to one wanting to revert to a powerful magnifying glass...

Comment: @CodeCaster It's not so much "let's make everything bigger" as it is "your screen is 5 inches big so it can't fit as much content on it".

Comment: Able to duplicate on iOS with Chrome and Opera. (I don't see a way to change the user agent in Safari.)

Comment: It works on Firefox, not on Webkit. That's... annoying.

Comment: (For those without mobile platforms, just enable developer tools in your favourite browser, they all have a responsive mode you can enable and look at different screen sizes).

Comment: I upvoted because I could reproduce it (I discovered the bug then came to meta hoping somebody else had already reported it) but now it appears fine whether I have responsiveness on or not. Are you still able to reproduce this? [A question on MSE about the same bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343217/284827) has *status-completed* added to it by the OP.

Comment: I can no longer reproduce in desktop FF by narrowing my window; it appears that the broken responsiveness has been disabled and it just goes horizontal scroll.

Comment: Looks like the change was reverted and we are back to the previous version.

Comment: Close-voters, do you really think it's appropriate to close a fixed bug as "can no longer be reproduced"? That's what [meta-tag:status-completed] is for, after all.

Comment: @John I did so myself, the other two votes are probably from review. Should I not have voted as non-repro as it was a problem for a few hours which was fixed in the meantime?